# How to fix a code with different results for a linear optimization problem with Pulp Gekko & Scipy package?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, pulp, gekko

I'm setting up a new linear optimization code with Python. Unfortunately, I don't have the same results with Pulp, Scipy and Gekko packages.

I tried to implement code with different packages for Linear Optimization in Python.

#### OPTIMIZATION WITH GEKKO

```
from gekko import GEKKO 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()             # create GEKKO model
x = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=400000)      # define new variable, initial     value=0
y = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=200)      # define new variable, initial value=1
z = m.Var(value=0, lb=0)

m.Equation(x+y+z==100)
m.Obj(1.2*x + y + z) # equations
m.solve(disp=False)     # solve

print("Solution with The GEKKO package")
print(x.value, y.value , z.value)# # print solution
```

#### OPTIMIZATION WITH Scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(m):
    x = m[0]
    y = m[1]
    z = m[2]
    return 1.2*x + y + z


def constraint1(m):
    return m[0] + m[1] + m[2] - 100

def constraint2(x):
    return x[2]

x0 = [0,0,0]
b1 = (0,400000)
b2 = (0,200)
b3= (0,None)
bnds = (b1,b2,b3)

con1 = {'type' : 'eq', 'fun' : constraint1}
con2 = {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : constraint2}
cons = [con1,con2]

sol = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds , constraints=cons)

print("Solution with The SCIPY package")
print(sol)
```

#### OPTIMIZATION WITH PULP

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("Problem",LpMinimize)

x = LpVariable("X",0,400000,LpContinuous)
y = LpVariable("Y",0,200,LpContinuous)
z = LpVariable("Z",0,None,LpContinuous)

prob += 1.2*x + y + z
prob += (x + y + z == 100)
prob.solve()

print("Solution with The PULP package")
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

**I expect to have the same results**, but the actual outputs are Different unfortunately :

#### The solution with The GEKKO package

```
[0.0] [36.210291349] [63.789708661]
```

#### The solution with The SCIPY package

```
fun: 100.0000000000001
jac: array([1.19999981, 1.        , 1.        ]) 
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 35
nit: 7
njev: 7
status: 0
success: True
x: array([4.88498131e-13, 5.00000000e+01, 5.00000000e+01])
```

#### The Solution with The PULP package

```
X = 0.0
Y = 100.0
Z = 0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All results are correct / Every solver is correct!**

- Each solution is reaching the minimum in it's objective: `100`.
- Each solution is preserving the variable-bounds
- Each solution is preserving the "simplex-like" contraint: `sum(x) = 100`

Ignoring floating-point limitations, there are infinitely many different optimal solutions for your problem.

Different solvers including different solving approaches can lead to different solutions (picking one of many solutions). Here for example:

- LP-algorithms like Simplex (Pulp)
- NLP-algorithms like sequential least squares (scipy)

  - (keep in mind: there are also LP-solvers within scipy and more specialized solvers are usually better given some a-priori defined optimization problem -> LP vs. NLP)

Comment: Does scipy have another method besides "SLSQP" for Linear Optimization Problems? I know there are so many but I do not know which one fits most to this problem!

Comment: [Sure](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/optimize.html#linear-programming), but i can't recommend the Simplex-based solver.

Comment: @AzizB.Ammar: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem (you can do so by clicking the small check next to the answer which then turns green).